# Reference a cell as a string within a formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

**I need to pass the contents of a cell to a formula, but formatted as a string.**

In column A, I have a series of dates, formatted DD/MM/YYYY (ie 01/11/2013, 02/11/2013 and so on).

Column B is a total $ value which is a SUMIF that looks up against a sheet of raw data and sums any lines that match that date, as per the below formula (this works, currently)

```
=SUMIF('Raw Data'!$J:J,"01/10/2013",'Raw Data'!Q:Q)
```

Currently, the process is to time-consumingly replace the date in each formula - i.e. the date is hard-coded into the formula as a string (the sheet it is looking up requires a string in quotation marks).

What I want to do is replace the "01/10/2013" with a reference to cell A1, so the formula can simply be copied down for the range of dates.

However if I go:

```
=SUMIF('Raw Data'!$J:J,A1,'Raw Data'!Q:Q)
```

It doesn't work as the lookup requires the date to be surrounded by quotation marks.

It's possible to add quotation marks with:

```
=""""&TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")&""""
```

This returns A1 with quotation marks around it. However, when inserted into the formula as follows:

```
=SUMIF('Raw Data'!$J:J,""""&TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")&"""",'Raw Data'!Q:Q)
```

It doesn't work and returns nothing. I think this is due to the fact the formula is passing another formula (the formula that adds the quotation marks) rather than the actual string.

Any ideas?

NOTE:

- The solution cannot use macros (this might be a deal-breaker, i.e. it might be impossible to do it without macros, but we aren't able to run them). If it is impossible that's fine, please just let me know.
- I can't simply add quotation marks to the dates in column A; they need to be displayed as DD/MM/YYYY not "DD/MM/YYYY"

Comment: So the dates you are looking up against in the sheet of raw data have quotation marks around them? If so, your formula above - `=""""&TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")&""""` - works for me, I think. If there are no quotes on the other sheet, using just the TEXT part of that formula works.

Comment: The raw data dates are formatted as DD/MM/YYYY and D/MM/YYYY (ie it displays both 6/11/13 and 22/22/13). They come from a CSV and are pasted into the raw data tab.

Comment: If I change the formula to have the date hard coded but without the quotation marks it doesn't work, so they are definitely required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=SUMIF('Raw Data'!$J:J,A1,'Raw Data'!Q:Q)` works where A1 contains 41548, whether formatted General or as 01 October 2013 when formatted Long Date (or otherwise) and whether dates in raw data are strings (eg 01/10/2013) or date serial numbers, provided not within inverted commas.

Comment: `=cell("format",[the raw data date cells])` returns D1 as the date format, though I'm not sure what that means. If I just use the A1 reference and don't hard code it it returns 0, which I assume means the sumif isn't matching the date where it should.

Comment: I should note too, that even if I change A1 to "01/11/2013", which is exactly the same format (with the quotation marks) that is hard coded into the formula, if I then reference A1 it doesn't work. It only works if the date is in the formula (no references work at all).

Comment: Brilliant - that worked! I fixed it by copying a date format from the raw data to the report page, then using the format painter. Now it works with just the A1 as a reference (no need for quotation marks). Thanks all!